# List a shared OneDrive folder contents

Tags: javascript, html, onedrive

I know I can get an embedded link for a OneDrive folder/file, but I am wondering if it is possible to have more control over the displayed contents. I run the sound room at our church and want to make adding sermons to the website super easy by using OneDrive. The plan would be to link the folder to the website and when I add a new file (.mp3) the website would be able to make a clickable link. I was hoping to use the public directory to avoid any authorization, but I do not want to use the embed link since I can not control how the files are shown and it also ruins the flow of the site.

So is it possible for php, aspx, JavaScript or any other web based tech to access the folder and give me a JSON list of the contents so I can display them myself? Would prefer JavaScript if possible, then php since I am not sure if my webhost has aspx on our current plan (I doubt they do)

I have started looking through the API, but from what I can see you need to sign-in to OneDrive to use the API at all.

Maybe it is not possible, but would be awesome if it was.

Comment: I believe the only way to do this with OneDrive is via embedding.

Comment: I am afraid of that. I was just hoping I was not the only person out there that wanted to do this, and if I was not that maybe someone had found a way.